# Python groupby and delete certain rows only

Tags: python, pandas

A.       B.         C.
102    12/2019       looking
102    01/2020       won
102    02/2020       archived
102    03/2020       deleted
101    12/2019       looking
101    01/2020       won
101    02/2020       won
101    03/2020       won

I want to delete all reiterations (records/rows) when a certain A goes to won but ONLY if it stays at won (A=101).  But if it goes from won to something else then I want it in the data.

result:
A.       B.         C.
102    12/2019       looking
102    01/2020       won
102    02/2020       archived
102    03/2020       deleted
101    12/2019       looking
101    01/2020       won

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with chained conditions with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with inverse mask by `~`:

```
df = df[~(df.duplicated(['A','C']) & df['C'].eq('won'))]
print (df)
     A        B         C
0  102  12/2019   looking
1  102  01/2020       won
2  102  02/2020  archived
3  102  03/2020   deleted
4  101  12/2019   looking
5  101  01/2020       won
```

Comment: So there are 100s of contract numbers in column A like 101 and they have unlimited time series (column B). and not all contracts go to won but I need those anyway